# Help to obtain the solution of this integral, which arises from the Biot-Savart law for magnetic field?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the magnetic field at an arbitrary point in space $(x,y,z)$ due to an infinitely thin current-carrying sheet confined to the $z=0$ plane, with width $W$ and length $L$. To do this, I proceeded to integrate the current density via the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#Electric_current_density_(throughout_conductor_volume)) for the geometry in question, and have got stuck at the following integral for one of the field components:
$$
B_x(x,y,z) = \int_{-L}^{+L} \frac{z}{(y-y')^2+z^2}\Bigg( \frac{x-W}{\sqrt{(x-W)^2+(y-y')^2+z^2}} - \frac{x+W}{\sqrt{(x+W)^2+(y-y')^2+z^2}} \Bigg)  \; \textrm{d}y' 
$$
(assuming all variables are real, and $W$ and $L$ are positive).

Defining $a=x-W$, $b=y$, and $c=z$ (constants for the purposes of integration over $y'$), I have tried to enter the first term into Wolfram Alpha, with the following result which contains a problematic imaginary $\sqrt{-c^2}$ term:

[image]

Since the integral is representing a magnetic field, I don't believe this result is physically correct.

Can anyone offer assitance with solving the integral?

Many thanks!

Edit:
My result using Mathematica

[image]

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @teeeeee, You could use the following result: $$\int\!\!\frac{dx}{\left(x^2\!+\!a^2\right)\!\!\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}\!=\!\frac1{a\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\arctan\left(\!\frac{x\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}{a\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}\!\right)\!+\!C$$

where $\,b>a>0\,.$

Comment: @teeeeee, it is arctan that is the inverse function of tangent.

Comment: @teeeeee, that result you found is correct only if $\,a>b>0\,,\,$ but you need a result in which $\,b>a>0\,$.

Comment: @ teeeeee Now, if you *really* want a challenge, try figuring out how you'd integrate $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left[(x-c)^{2}+d^{2}\right]\sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+b^{2}}}$ where $a\neq c$. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate your integral, you just need to change the integration variable $\,x’\!\!:=y-y’\,$ and use twice the result that I wrote in my comment,
first with $\,a=|z|$, $\,b=\sqrt{\left(x-W\right)^2+z^2}\,$ and then with $\,a=|z|$, $\,b=\sqrt{\left(x+W\right)^2+z^2}\,.\\$

**Addendum :**

It results that

$\begin{align}-\arctan&\left(\!\!\dfrac{a^2\!+\!x^2\!-\!x\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}{a\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\!\right)=\\
&\!\!\!\!=\arctan\left(\!\!\dfrac{x\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}{a\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}\!\right)-\arctan\left(\!\!\dfrac a{\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\!\!\right)\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}
\end{align}$

It is possible to prove the equality $\,(*)\,$ by differentiating both LHS and RHS and verifying they have the same derivative.

Consequently ,

$\dfrac{\sqrt{-a^2+b^2}\arctan\left[\dfrac{a^2+x\left(x-\sqrt{b^2+x^2}\right)}{a\sqrt{-a^2+b^2}}\right]}{a^3-ab^2}=$

$=\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\arctan\left(\!\dfrac{a^2+x^2-x\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}{a\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\!\right)}{a\left(a^2-b^2\right)}=$

$=-\dfrac1{a\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\,\arctan\left(\!\dfrac{a^2+x^2-x\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}{a\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\!\right)=$

$=\dfrac1{a\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\!\left[\arctan\left(\!\!\dfrac{x\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}{a\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}\!\right)-\arctan\left(\!\!\dfrac a{\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\!\!\right)\right]\!\!=$

$=\dfrac1{a\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}\,\arctan\left(\!\dfrac{x\sqrt{b^2\!-\!a^2}}{a\sqrt{x^2\!+\!b^2}}\!\right)+\text{constant}\;.$

Comment: Angelo, I am getting a different result to you when I input your integral into Mathematica (see the screenshot in my edit to the question). Can you see what might be the discrepancy?

Comment: @teeeeee, look at the addendum in my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Great. So now I have 2 questions if you don't mind! 1) Is the equality you quoted in the addendum given by some standard angle trigonometric identity? 2) Did you choose to orginally write the form of the integral result in the way you did in the comment because you found it in some standard integral table? Just curious! Thanks

Comment: @teeeeee, yes it is, indeed there exist formulas about addition and subtraction of arctangents. No, I did not find the integral result in any table, I just got it by a substitution $$t=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}$$